# Redirect url from one server to another server?

Tags: tomcat6

We are having a web application deployed in Tomcat 6 in two different servers. I want to redirect the url to second server if the first server is down.
Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in many ways... depending on your architecture

You can [cluster](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) your tomcats, or put a load-balancer in front of it (replicated for assuring high availability of the entry point)

You can have a round robin DNS entry with a minimal TTL, or if you have access to your DNSs, you can change your DNS entry when a server is down (It's pretty a hack, though)

Cheers

Grooveek